# Global Validity of Locally Inertial Coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, equivalence-principle

Equivalence principle tells us that for a freely falling inertial observer spacetime is locally flat. The coordinate transformation needed to introduce Locally Inertial Coordinates were discusses in this [response](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/58204/168015). However, I have studied in general relativity that no coordinate system is globally inertial and so there is a limit on the size of LIC where it holds upto a good approximation, a solution to Einstein Field Equation. However, I have a different question here. For an observer at infinity, the schwarzschild time coordinate is his proper coordinate. On the wordline of the static observer at infinity the metric tensor is flat which follows all the assumptions of Equivalence principle. It was discussed in chapter 13 of MTW in equation 13.71 that metric tensor for a non-inertial observer spacetime is locally a mixture of rindler and born metric. [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3937v1) paper discusses the non-inertial observers in general relativity but it didn't explicity give us the form of metric tensor. So I am wondering, metric tensor for the static observer in space would be the vacuum solution and hence should be achievable through coordinate transformation of schwarzschild metric. It would be flat on the worldline of that static observer and vary as go away from the worldline. In this manner, we are basically setting up a coordinate which behaves like LIC around the observer and includes curvature effects as we go away from it?